# Using Holo themes in conjunction with AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

I have a fairly simple app in android which uses the Support Library to provide an Actionbar for devices running on APIs lower than **11**, so my main activity extends the [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).
My current app theme is as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

After running some tests and making sure the app works as expected, I've decided to set the theme for devices running on API level **14** and above as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

The app has been crashing on startup ever since.
The logcat shows that an exception is being thrown, which says the following:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Does it mean that I must use only the AppCompat themes, regardless of the device's API?
If not, then how should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that I must use only the AppCompat themes, regardless of the device's API?

Yes. Or, stop using `appcompat-v7`, and inherit from `Activity`.

Comment: Isn't there any workaround to make the app support older devices and still be able to deliver fancy themes to the newer ones?

Comment: @TimorGruber: Make your fancy themes be based off of `Theme.AppCompat` rather than `Theme.Holo`. I am unclear what "fancy" you are doing that would work with `Theme.Holo` but not `Theme.AppCompat`. There are older, deprecated action bar backports (e.g., ActionBarSherlock), but it is difficult to recommend them at this time. Or, since [Android 2.x is under 5% of the Google Play ecosystem at this time](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), set your `minSdkVersion` to 15 and switch to the native action bar.

Comment: By fancy I mean stylish, cause the Holo themes looks a bit more "modern" than the AppCompat themes.
Anyway, thanks for the help, I'll consider your advice.

Comment: @TimorGruber: Considering that the `AppCompat` theme is designed to mimic, within limits, the `Theme.Material` that is the default for Android 5.0+, you have an interesting definition of "modern".

Comment: @CommonsWare Sassy!